# Why is SQL the only database query language?

Tags: database, programming-languages, sql

For general-purpose programming there are literally hundreds of programming languages. But for interacting/querying the databases, why is SQL pretty much the only used language?

Comment: Database languages are tied to the database. Oracle uses one dialect, Sql Server uses another, MySql uses another one, and so on. Sure, they are _similar_, in the same sense that Java and C# are similar, but they are not the same.

Comment: @ThalesPereira: SQL dialects are much more alike than C# and Java. Most SQL will work on every SQL database.

Comment: @kevincline My argument was meant to illustrate, not really to be literal.

Comment: Have you created an alternative language to use?

Comment: @GrandmasterB: We could always consider resurrecting [quel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUEL_query_languages).

Comment: Good question. Given how many compile-to-javascript efforts we've seen, I'm surprised we don't have many (any?) compile-to-SQL projects. In fact I've been thinking about writing my own, since I love relational DBs but don't much like SQL.

Comment: How many languages can your processor run? It's where they all end up isn't it? Feel free to create another language and then compile or interpret it into what a database understands.

Comment: EF and other orms are effectivly compile to sql

Comment: Just an opinion, but I think people who don't like SQL are probably given to over normalizing databases (i.e. making too many tables). Sure if you have a billion unnecessary tables that you have to join together in every query with a billion foreign keys, you'll hate SQL. But its your own fault not SQL's/

Comment: This applies mainly to relational databases. My filesystem does not accept SQL nor does my Minecraft world.

Comment: @developerwjk: people who don't like normalized databases should do something else. Table joins are the basis of a *relational* database, and along with foreign keys and constraints create the foundation of a database that can protect itself (i.e. enforce data integrity). The database will outlive the app. I realize it has become popular to disparage databases these days, but that's a little immature, IMO. There's a place for denormalized databases (data warehouses), but there are too many sloppy, inconsistent databases out there causing errors and requiring excessive maintenance.

Comment: @developerwjk Doesn't apply to those who hate SQL and like LINQ.

Comment: @default.kramer In the .NET world there is LINQ and one of my former employers had an in-house DSL for SQL in C++. But you're right, SQL and Javascript are similar problems in that way.

Comment: @Craig, I said over-normalized. If you get more than 3 or more tables to join, you're doing it wrong, and you'll end up hating SQL as a result.

Comment: Nah, joining 3 tables is fine. If you get over about 7 tables you might start running into performance issues. Use too many flag fields (or "binary state indicators" as we used to say) and you'll end up hating your database, too.   ;-)  I guess if you're using some tool that arranges all your joins in nested sets of parenthesis you might end up *thinking* you hate SQL.

Comment: The recent StackOverflow survey got me thinking about DB languages and led me to this question because I was curious: why does SQL get listed as a language but Mongo / NoSQL do not? I imagine there's an obvious reason that I'm not thinking of, but it seems odd to include SQL somewhere, but not Mongo / NoSQL

Comment: I just find LINQ's from -> where -> select so much more intuitive than select -> where -> from I'd be happy with a SQL language that did that, i.e. input first, followed by map / reduce functions, followed by output

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In addition to Basile's answer, please also recognize that SQL is not a language like you would think of an object-oriented language or procedural language. In many ways the ANSI SQL standard is more like a protocol or a series of generally accepted statements based on mathematical principles of [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory), [predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_logic) and [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra).

But how individual [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) developers implement these standards vary significantly across various proprietary software enough so to almost classify each individual implementation as a language of its own.

For instance, Oracle SQL is quite different from Microsoft SQL Server SQL which is different to [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), etc. On top of this, each company implements their own unique functions, database engine and (in some cases) procedural languages on top of the traditional ANSI SQL standard statements. Some even choose to abandon the standard at times in favor of their own personal implementation.

The history of this marriage of SQL to the relational model is primarily due to the fact that the technology and language were developed side-by-side in the 1970s by [E.F. Codd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd), Donald D. Chamberlin and Raymond F. Boyce. There are some pretty decent articles on Wikipedia around the topic if you have an opportunity to read about it.

Comment: How can you talk about mathematical foundations of SQL without mentioning [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)?

Comment: @svick - Ah! Quite true! Thank you for the correction!

Comment: @Dank Thanks for the point about RDBMS technology and SQL development happening side-by-side. That probably is a big factor that prevented multiple/disparate query languages (even if its just a standard, in areas like networking its common to have multiple, incompatible standards for one feature) evolving.

Comment: A shorter name for "Microsoft SQL Server SQL" would be T-SQL, or *Transact-SQL*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Are you sure about that? I always thought that T-SQL was Microsoft's procedural language on top of their ANSI SQL implementation much like PL/SQL is Oracle procedural language on top of the Oracle SQL implementation. In other words I've always treated them as separate languages.

Comment: [T-SQL (Transact-SQL) is a set of programming extensions from Sybase and Microsoft that add several features to the Structured Query Language (SQL) including transaction control, exception and error handling, row processing, and declared variables. Microsoft's SQL Server and Sybase's SQL server support T-SQL statements.](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/T-SQL) - I've always seen T-SQL as "SQL Server -flavored SQL"

Comment: This made me think that JavaScript is not a language.

Comment: Many languages are not programming languages. HTML for example. That really has no bearing on the question of why SQL is ubiquitous in the relational world. XML got replaced by JSON, because JSON doesn't suck as much. And yet no one has delivered us from SQL. It's legitimate to ask why.

Comment: @Theraot well, it's not, it's a broad term used to refer to many different implementations and standards... /s

Comment: @cat We could say something similar about C#, C++, or even assembly. At best a language only exists an specification, at worst there is no distinction between a language and its implementation. Edit: I'm not arguing whatever or not JavaScript is a language, I'm just saying that this made me think about that.

Comment: @Theraot sure but `/s` is intended to signal sarcasm, sorry :-)

Comment: @John: JSON did not replace XML. XML, love it or hate it, is alive and well. Well-formed HTML is, itself, essentially XML. JSON *did* gain favor in specific contexts where it makes sense. The longevity of SQL (1974, first implemented commercially in Oracle in 1979), is a testament to the elegance and power and frankly the simplicity of the solution. Innumerable overblown ORM and CASE tools and NoSQL databases have tried to kill it without success. It's that good. Like JSON, NoSQL is useful in narrow contexts, but so far is just NOT the general purpose solution SQL and relational dbms's are.

Comment: @Craig NoSQL doesn't attack SQL, despite the name. It attacks the relational paradigm. We're talking about alternatives to SQL within the relational paradigm. - And html isn't xml, it just looks similar, and other uses of xml are in decline in favor of json. Why not do the same for SQL? Just a nicer syntax that has a decent DOM in the way html, xml and json has?

Comment: HTML is, in specific point of fact, a dialect of SGML, the same as XML. They actually are the same thing, right down to the fact that there is an XML schema for XHTML, which of course has now been succeeded by HTML5. The XML doctype for HTML5 is, ahem, <!DOCTYPE html>. Yes, they are the same thing. JSON is handy in specific narrow contexts. For pure machine to machine communications of structured data, JSON has no advantage, and like any other technology, it will get applied where it shouldn't

Comment: HTML and XML are both dialects of XML, so you are right in that sense. It's still just a dialect and XML parsers can't parse HTML because the details are different. Interestingly, SGML parser also couldn't parse HTML4 and below. XML parsers could parse XHTML, but browsers never parsed it that way so it was always just an academic consideration that never had any bearing in practice. JSON is easier to read, the parsers simpler to implement, it produces shorter serializations and the standard is sane and free from legacy crap (see DTDs). It's mostly just better.

Comment: @John: this is getting silly. Of course it has bearing in practice, it's part of the point of the semantic web. It's okay if you take a day to read up about that before responding, too. If an XML parser can't parse XHTML or HTML5, which are the most recent standards, it's because the HTML isn't well-formed, which is on the so-called "web dev," not on the standard. *Every* XML schema's details are different, not just HTML's. What are you talking about?

Comment: DTD's (which are from SGML, not XML) are still useful. It all depends on the context. JSON is fine where it's appropriate, but it isn't appropriate everywhere. Likewise, I really hate using XML where JSON is more appropriate. But neither one is universally "better" than the other. I went looking around just now for something that could provide you withe more context, while not requiring me to type a lot more. Have a look at this: http://www.yegor256.com/2015/11/16/json-vs-xml.html

Comment: @Craig I said XML parsers *can* read XHTML - so what are *you* talking about? I said they can't parse HTML4 or HTML5 - and that's just true. For a start HTML4 and HTML5 don't need all tags closed, XML does. It's pretty obvious, really. And yes, I did spent "more than a day". I probably wasted more than a month of my life dealing with those pre-what-wg retarded W3C standards back when I believed these people knew what they were doing. Did you?

Comment: http://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol14/print/Fearon01/BalisageVol14-Fearon01.html

Answer (score 23):

First SQL is mostly for [*relational* databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). And it has multiple variants or dialects.

So non-relational databases have other query languages. Read about [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL). Look into [MongoDB](http://mongodb.com/) for example. See also [Query language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_language) wikipage listing other query languages.

Comment: Those other DBs necessarily have other query languages, because SQL only makes sense in a relational world. The fact remains that (almost) everywhere, where SQL does make some sense, it's actually used. Even though it's arguably pretty horrid.

Comment: @John It does have some warts, but I think it's actually pretty elegant for the problem it's designed to solve.

Comment: SQL is *awesome* for the problem it was designed to solve, and the various NoSQL solutions do not make relational databases obsolete, by any stretch. Just talk to a software engineering team that has gone through multiple generations of a product based on a NoSQL database, with its umpteen different but similar ad-hoc schemas in the same database and you'll gain an appreciation for just how good relational databases and SQL actually are.

Comment: @Craig Had to come back here after I found a new "favorite most ridiculous syntax issue in sql": The merge statement. An "upsert" operation forces you to mention all involved column names at least 4 (!) times - two times each in the insert and update clauses. In addition, the language designers made sure that the syntax for insert and update are different enough to prevent the use of copy-and-paste. For tables with many columns, it's easier to write a script to construct the merge statement than to write it by hand.

Answer (score 12):

SQL is not a "language" per se, so much as it is a standard for making a language. See [The SQL Timeline](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/ansi-sql-standards/) for reference. Multiple parties have implemented specific database query languages based on the standard, which vary in the degree to which the standard is adhered to.

In that sense, it is false to say that SQL is the only database query language, as there is no such thing as "the SQL language"; rather you have multiple language implementations, such as Transact-SQL (e.g. as used by Microsoft SQL Server), MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle SQL, and so on, which are similar in many aspects, but are largely not compatible with each other due to being designed for the domain of a specific relational database engine.

As Basile Starynkevitch [correctly pointed out](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/334290/140090), there are also multiple "NoSQL" database languages which can be implemented via APIs that can be used by most traditional programming languages.

Comment: *there is no such thing as "the Structured Query Language language"*; *Structured Query Language is not a "language"* does sound a bit weird, but nice answer.

Comment: @Mat'sMug it felt weird writing it as well, I know what you mean. Alas, thus is the nature of SQL!

Comment: Those points apply to many other languages as well though: C, C++, C#, Java, etc. In fact, there are only a few such as PHP and Perl that are sufficiently bizarre to prevent having a standard and competing implementations.

Answer (score 6):

## Good ol' Uncle Bob

I'd encourage you to consider what [Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin has to say on databases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nsjsiz2A9mg&feature=youtu.be&t=42m17s). I find it interesting, with regards to some considerations he discusses regarding SQL and NoSQL.

## TLDR

SQL popularity was influenced by corporate entities, the open source community, technology stacks like [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29), and physical storage limitations of hard drives. As of 2016, your [top three](https://jaxenter.com/the-top-10-sql-and-nosql-databases-108072.html) database systems are all SQL-based (Oracle 12c, [Microsoft SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), and MySQL). It was also pointed out in the comments below that SQL has been an approved standard for both [ANSI](https://ansi.org/),(American National Standards Institute), and the [ISO International Standards Organization](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9075:-1:ed-4:v1:en) for decades, which has vast impacts on its predictability and quality - a very important business consideration for many enterprises.

---

## Physical Storage Considerations

Until the wide-spread appearance of SSDs and cloud computing within the last decade, SQL was the predominant leader in database languages; with these new technologies, however, a new evolution of database languages are appearing as well. There have been some articles discussing the [closing gap in price and increase in both popularity and accessibility](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3040694/data-storage/ssd-prices-plummet-again-close-in-on-hdds.html#tk.drr_mlt) of SSDs over HDDs. There's a great website for [**ranking of database technologies**](http://db-engines.com/en/ranking) available, which might interest you. You can see that SQL and relational databases still have a firm foot-hold, but NoSQL alternatives such as MongoDB are [creeping up as well](https://www.marketresearchmedia.com/?p=568).

## The Goliaths

[SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) has gained increasing popularity over the past several decades since it really took off in the mid 1980s. Today, the "concrete" nature of its popularity can be considered with regards to two of the most influential companies on the planet, whose enterprise products rely largely on solutions revolving around the SQL language. Those two companies are: Oracle and Microsoft. Countless small, mid, and large-sized companies use Oracle and Microsoft products, such as [Oracle 12c, Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL](https://jaxenter.com/the-top-10-sql-and-nosql-databases-108072.html). It's also important to note the impact of the open-source community as well, which over the past 20 years or so in which it was very common to see many developers using PHP and MySQL together through things like the LAMP, [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP), [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), and [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) stacks.

Both companies, Microsoft and Oracle, are software goliaths, and the OOP programming languages they provide are two of the most popular: Java and C#.

Java, being acquired by Oracle about 6 years ago, is one of the most popular programming languages in the world. Hence, Oracle has a very vested interest in making sure that its programming language is used in tandem with MySQL, which is the source of a very high revenue for the company.

C#, being owned by Microsoft, integrates very well with SQL Server through Microsoft's various database offerings, such as through cloud storage in Azure as well as local installations of Windows Server, which typically runs with an instance of [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx).

Other popular languages like PHP also integrate well with MySQL, due to the open-source nature of those languages. The LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP), as well as MAMP, XAMP, and WAMP, also provided a foray into a mix of easy-to-use out-of-the-box open-source technologies that were all the rave about 20 years ago (and still are very popular to this day).

The open-source community around these languages (in particular, SQL) are huge, so it is quite easy to find support.

The language itself is also very easy to understand and read, given that it is very close to how you would structure a logical English sentence (if there is such a thing!).

## Some Competition

However, while SQL and other relational databases are holding strong, other alternative document store technologies, like NoSQL, [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB) and Microsoft's NoSQL implementations are becoming [increasingly popular as well](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/nosql-keeps-rising-but-relational-databases-still-dominate-big-data/).

### Physical Tech Advances

Part of this increase in the use of NoSQL-esque platforms may be due to the physical hardware technologies that are settling into the market. As SSDs and HDDs are becoming [more closely comparable in price](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3040694/data-storage/ssd-prices-plummet-again-close-in-on-hdds.html#tk.drr_mlt), storing data in the form of large JSON documents and in repository and [object storage systems](http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/tip/Nine-reasons-object-level-storage-adoption-has-increased), such as [Amazon S3 Storage](http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Amazon-S3-storage-101-Object-storage-in-the-cloud) becomes relatively less expensive, both physically and fiscally, whether you are considering storing it on your own hard drive locally or somewhere in the cloud.

### Cloud Offerings

Cloud offerings are becoming cheaper by the day, and 1 TB of storage in the cloud is practically [dirt cheap as well](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/onedrive-dropbox-google-drive-and-box-which-cloud-storage-service-is-right-for-you/). I personally have 1 TB of Google Drive storage for $1.99 per month (about $25 per year).

## Some Conclusions...

Storage space (physically) used to be a crucial issue, which is where many SQL databases stood to serve a need for a data language that could be used to keep data storage as efficient as possible. This is where you get the [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) style applications (Create, Read, Update, Delete). When storing massive amounts of data in a SQL database, you want to avoid duplication as much as possible through a process known as normalization, which has to do with designing the database in such a way as to have as efficient of a relational mapping as possible. This would help the physical lookup speed (also improved through indexing), but all of which was centered around a major concern, which was physical space. You simply couldn't afford to have massive amounts of duplicate data. Not to mention, the need for database replication and backup, to protect against things like natural disasters or power outages, terrorists, etc.

Huge companies with massive amounts of credit card data or health information couldn't afford to go down for even a minute, so they would need to replicate and distribute their data centers geographically to protect their users' data. This was enormously expensive, because every database needed a physical endpoint, a computer and a hard drive to store the mass of information.

Fast forward to today, the need for physical size is less expensive. We'll likely see a shift away from SQL over the coming years, but it has such a large user base, and many large companies are so firmly rooted, that this will likely take a while.

However, new industries, such as infrastructure as a service, provided by companies like Amazon with their [Amazon Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) (AWS) - as well as Microsoft [Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure), large scalable datacenters filled to the brim with high-capacity, lower-power consuming SSD hard drives are making it increasingly possible for those large companies to port over to newer, more efficient technologies. As a result, we will likely see the change in database language to reflect new physical, logical, and other scientific limitations.

Comment: You are getting something like 15 years late to the party - Sql was already popular way before C# was even a thing, and Java only got owned by oracle somewhat recently.

Comment: You're right, there's some ambiguity to what I was trying to say, which is why it's *currently* so popular. I'll revise. Thanks!

Comment: @ThalesPereira how about the rest of it, any other thoughts?

Comment: **tl;dr:** "SQL has large corporate sponsors."

Comment: That's not really what the post says :P. In summary, it's more of a holistic view of how SQL popularity was influenced by corporate entities, the open source community, technology stacks like LAMP, and physical storage limitations of hard drives until the appearance of SSD's and cloud computing.

Comment: Well... SSD's aren't the answer to storage limitations; dollar for dollar, SSD's store *less data, not more.*   SSD's are about improving performance.  SQL is an *actual* standard, not a defacto one.  I would argue that the principal driver for other database technologies like "NoSQL" is specialized applications like "big data," not storage technologies.

Comment: True, I should have put more emphasis on the *trend* we're seeing with the price and popularity of SSD's getting closer to HDD's. Here's an interesting article about the [closing parity between SSD and HDD's](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3040694/data-storage/ssd-prices-plummet-again-close-in-on-hdds.html#tk.drr_mlt). Out of curiosity what do you mean by SQL being an actual standard versus a defacto one?

Comment: Actual standard in the sense of being steered by a committee and being [approved](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/2008/07/sql2008-now-an-approved-iso-international-standard/) by a standards body (e.g. OSI, NIST, ANSI etc).

Comment: "Finally, the world is slowly moving away from SQL as data structures like JSON get more prevalent." [citation needed] I would bet that non-relational storage is indeed getting more popular but that doesn't mean relational DBs are getting less popular.

Comment: @StijndeWitt thank you for the clarification, the light just turned on :].

Comment: @default.kramer roger that, I'll find a citation for that statement. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyBullis Ok! The link I posted is broken btw. This is the best replacement I could find: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:9075:-1:ed-4:v1:en *(very technical)*

Comment: Normalization is not about saving storage space and never has been. Normalization is about avoiding duplication of data which results in inconsistency of the dataset and errors.

Comment: Avoiding duplication does help save space as well as improving efficiency. I think the point is that saving space is more of a byproduct of normalization, not the main goal. I didn't mean to make it sound as such.

Answer (score 5):

That is a very good question, but you could more generally ask:

*Why are all relational databases so remarkably similar?*

Apart from the smaller variants that come with a GUI such as Access and Filemaker and the somewhat special single-user engines, relational databases all share an astounding number of peculiarities:

- As is already part of your question, they all use the same (old and flawed) query language to which they all add new features. It's the worst of both worlds: No one dares to innovate away from SQL, but the dialects are still not compatible.
- Even though the database schema is also always defined using this language (with DDL), databases don't return the current schema in that form. Rather, they usually return it in the form of various forms of tabular data. Many have client-side utilities that can then convert that information back to DDL. Which, of course, is a pain to do diffs on programmatically for updates. Bizarre, but that's how they all do it.
- They can't give you a live view of a query: The result set together with a real-time feed of the changes. That's why database applications re-query everything all the time.
- Even though they all support the concept of constraints, especially in the form of foreign and unique keys, none of them provide calling code with enough information for that calling code to understand which of those constraints was violated when that happens. That is why database-backed software still needs to do explicit uniqueness and foreign key checking - a violation of DRY and a pain.
- They are bad at giving information about why queries are slow, which is why database applications usually just hang without explanation when anything locky or expensive happens. Why can't I get a live view of the execution plan with progress indicators on the nodes (with links to locking queries if they come up)? [EDIT: Sql Server now indeed has "Live Query Statistics", very cool)
- They all have b-tree indexes for the common stuff and then they all have another two-dimensional index based on floating-point values for geographical applications. But only floating point, and only two dimensions. Then they usually have some full-text search capability extra. And more than one has extra index support for xml data the resides in string columns.
- They all have a method to measure the similarity of two words in English.
- They all can do aggregates, but none of them can keep aggregate partial values in b-tree branch nodes to do it fast.
- As a special instance of the previous point, none of them can efficiently seek to a row by row count. In particular, the common scroll-grids that lazily load the slice of data a user scrolled to are never efficient for a large number of rows - on none of the relational database servers. They all have to scan through all the data from the beginning of the result set to the first returned row. Let that sink in.

In short, even though they are all both incredibly amazing and indispensable for many data storage and processing tasks, they are also all confusing and quirky in a surprisingly similar way. You can see how after the first one was written everybody just copied it, and as time went by people added just the feature that was cool at the time and that then got copied to all players.

This is very different from programming platforms, where there are widely different paradigms and even widely different syntaxes within each paradigm. New ideas get hacked onto older language also, but more often people actually make new languages and platforms. Java was a step forward in 1990. .NET was a step forward in 2002. A language about as ancient as the relational database would be C++, and that shows. Only with relational databases, one has no real choice but to use them.

I know there are "NoSQL" databases, but the relational paradigm is still immensely important. It's sad that there is so little pluralism there.

Comment: Pretty much every bullet point seems to boil down to either (1) implementation choices (certain data structures tend to be highly efficient for certain types of data and processing, so to store that type of data and enable that type of processing, those data structures end up being used), or (2) availability of features (which in turn is a function of what customers are asking for). I don't think any of your points are actually about SQL per se.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Indeed, and they all make the same implementation choices and have roughly the same features. As if all customers wanted the same and there were no niches. As if software developers wanted the same as data warehouse people. Or, as I said, as if they all just copy one original.

Comment: This is a rant not an answer.

Comment: @PieterB It contributes more than your comment.

Comment: @John when downvoting you are encouraged by the site to state the reason for the downvote, which I did.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the only query language... Query languages have different flavours of implementation. Basically, SQL is taken as reference standards or internally other languages convert to SQL.

Some of the query languages are listed [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_language).

C# developers use the [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) query language very often.

Comment: Linq translates to SQL and as such there's an impedance. The main reason LINQ came to be is because the database engines, including SQL Server, don't have a proper query API that could be used directly.

Comment: Microsoft adopted extension methods into .NET (from Apple's Objective-C, which came out of Steve Jobs' NeXT in the 1980's). LINQ is nothing more or less than the most natural next thing to do with extension methods. LINQ to SQL, not to be conflated with LINQ (which has **nothing** to do with databases) was the natural evolution on the ORM front, which was already an old concept when Microsoft's released EF, which more people shy away from than you realize because it is colossal and slow and *still* leaks abstractions despite its attempt at enormous universality. Go Google Dapper. SQL is easy.

Comment: @Craig You need EF and LINQ for type safety, not because of SQL shortcomings as a language.

Comment: "Need" is a strong word.